# Hochschild homology of a Hopf algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, homology

Let $A$ be a Hopf algebra over the complex numbers.
Denote by $\mathcal{M}$ the dg-category of dg-$A$-modules.
The Hochschild homology of $\mathcal{M}$ is not going to be the Hochschild homology of $A$, but can I compute the Hochschild homology of $A$ as the Hochschild homology of a subcategory of $\mathcal{M}$, preferrably some subcategory of objects which are dualizable?

I know that I can take perfect modules, but this subcategory, for instance, might not contain the tensor unit of $\mathcal{M}$, which might be a problem.

In summary, my question is what are the dg-categories built from $A$ and its modules whose Hochschild homology gives me the Hochschild homology of $A$?